# How to optimise multiple if else statment with LINQ query?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I am making a search functionality for my project. How do I optimize my query which is having so many `if else` statements?

I am using `if else` statements for checking if there are any null values or not, but it increases code complexity and memory. I want to reduce it; how can I optimize my query so I have minimum number of `if else` statements in my query?

```
    public List<tbltask> gettaskssdata(int c, int userid, string a, string StartDate, string EndDate, string ProjectID, string statusid)
    {
        List<tbltask> tbtask = new List<tbltask>();

        var selectproject = entity.tbluserprojects.Where(x => x.user_id == userid).Select(x => x.Projectid);

        if (statusid != "" && ProjectID != "" && a != "" && StartDate != "" && EndDate != "")
        {
            int pid = Convert.ToInt32(ProjectID);
            int sid = Convert.ToInt32(statusid);
            DateTime sdate = Convert.ToDateTime(StartDate).Date;
            DateTime edate = Convert.ToDateTime(EndDate).Date;
            tbtask = entity.tbltasks.Include(x => x.tblproject).Include(x => x.tbUser).Where(x => selectproject.Contains(x.ProjectId) && (x.tblproject.company_id == c) && (x.tblproject.ProjectId == pid) && (x.tblstatu.StatusId == sid) && (x.TaskName.Contains(a) || x.tbUser.User_name.Contains(a)) && (x.StartDate >= sdate && x.EndDate <= edate)).OrderByDescending(x => x.ProjectId).ToList();
        }
        else if (statusid == "" && ProjectID != "" && a != "" && StartDate != "" && EndDate != "")
        {
            int pid = Convert.ToInt32(ProjectID);
            DateTime sdate = Convert.ToDateTime(StartDate).Date;
            DateTime edate = Convert.ToDateTime(EndDate).Date;
            tbtask = entity.tbltasks.Include(x => x.tblproject).Include(x => x.tbUser).Where(x => selectproject.Contains(x.ProjectId) && (x.tblproject.company_id == c) && (x.tblproject.ProjectId == pid) && (x.TaskName.Contains(a) || x.tbUser.User_name.Contains(a)) && (x.StartDate >= sdate && x.EndDate <= edate)).OrderByDescending(x => x.ProjectId).ToList();
        }
        else if (ProjectID == "" && statusid != "" && a != "" && StartDate != "" && EndDate != "")
        {
            int sid = Convert.ToInt32(statusid);
            DateTime sdate = Convert.ToDateTime(StartDate).Date;
            DateTime edate = Convert.ToDateTime(EndDate).Date;
            tbtask = entity.tbltasks.Include(x => x.tblproject).Include(x => x.tbUser).Where(x => selectproject.Contains(x.ProjectId) && (x.tblproject.company_id == c) && (x.tblstatu.StatusId == sid) && (x.TaskName.Contains(a) || x.tbUser.User_name.Contains(a)) && (x.StartDate >= sdate && x.EndDate <= edate)).OrderByDescending(x => x.ProjectId).ToList();
        }
        else if(ProjectID!="" && StartDate == "" && EndDate == "" && statusid == ""  && a == "")
        {
            int pid = Convert.ToInt32(ProjectID);
            tbtask = entity.tbltasks.Include(x => x.tblproject).Include(x => x.tbUser).Where(x => selectproject.Contains(x.ProjectId) && (x.tblproject.company_id == c) && (x.tblproject.ProjectId == pid)).OrderByDescending(x => x.ProjectId).ToList();

        }
        else if(statusid!="" && ProjectID=="" && StartDate == "" && EndDate == ""  && a == "")
        {
            int sid = Convert.ToInt32(statusid);
            tbtask = entity.tbltasks.Include(x => x.tblproject).Include(x => x.tbUser).Where(x => selectproject.Contains(x.ProjectId) && (x.tblproject.company_id == c) && (x.tblstatu.StatusId == sid) ).OrderByDescending(x => x.ProjectId).ToList();
        }
        else if (a == "" && StartDate != "" && EndDate != "" && ProjectID != "")
        {
            int pid = Convert.ToInt32(ProjectID);
            DateTime sdate = Convert.ToDateTime(StartDate).Date;
            DateTime edate = Convert.ToDateTime(EndDate).Date;
            tbtask = entity.tbltasks.Include(x => x.tblproject).Include(x => x.tbUser).Where(x => selectproject.Contains(x.ProjectId) && (x.tblproject.ProjectId == pid) && (x.StartDate >= sdate && x.EndDate <= edate)).OrderByDescending(x => x.ProjectId).ToList();

        }
        else if (StartDate == "" && EndDate == "" && statusid != "" && ProjectID != "" && a != "")
        {
            int pid = Convert.ToInt32(ProjectID);
            int sid = Convert.ToInt32(statusid);
            tbtask = entity.tbltasks.Include(x => x.tblproject).Include(x => x.tbUser).Where(x => selectproject.Contains(x.ProjectId) && (x.tblproject.company_id == c) && (x.tblproject.ProjectId == pid) && (x.tblstatu.StatusId == sid) && (x.TaskName.Contains(a) || x.tbUser.User_name.Contains(a))).OrderByDescending(x => x.ProjectId).ToList();
        }
        else if (a == "" && StartDate == "" && EndDate == "" && ProjectID != "" && statusid != "")
        {
            int pid = Convert.ToInt32(ProjectID);
            int sid = Convert.ToInt32(statusid);
            tbtask = entity.tbltasks.Include(x => x.tblproject).Include(x => x.tbUser).Include(x => x.tblstatu).Where(x => selectproject.Contains(x.ProjectId) && x.tblproject.company_id == c && x.tblproject.ProjectId == pid && x.tblstatu.StatusId == sid).OrderByDescending(x => x.ProjectId).ToList();
        }
        else if (a != "" && StartDate == "" && EndDate == "" && ProjectID == "" && statusid == "")
        {
            tbtask = entity.tbltasks.Include(x => x.tblproject).Include(x => x.tbUser).Where(x => selectproject.Contains(x.ProjectId) && (x.tblproject.company_id == c) && (x.TaskName.Contains(a) || x.tbUser.User_name.Contains(a))).OrderByDescending(x => x.ProjectId).ToList();

        }
        else if (a != "" && ProjectID != "" && StartDate == "" && EndDate == "" && statusid == "")
        {
            int pid = Convert.ToInt32(ProjectID);
            tbtask = entity.tbltasks.Include(x => x.tblproject).Include(x => x.tbUser).Where(x => selectproject.Contains(x.ProjectId) && (x.tblproject.company_id == c) && (x.tblproject.ProjectId == pid) && (x.TaskName.Contains(a) || x.tbUser.User_name.Contains(a))).OrderByDescending(x => x.ProjectId).ToList();
        }
        else if (a != "" && StartDate != "" && EndDate != "" && ProjectID == "" && statusid == "")
        {
            DateTime sdate = Convert.ToDateTime(StartDate).Date;
            DateTime edate = Convert.ToDateTime(EndDate).Date;
            tbtask = entity.tbltasks.Include(x => x.tblproject).Include(x => x.tbUser).Where(x => selectproject.Contains(x.ProjectId) && (x.tblproject.company_id == c) && (x.TaskName.Contains(a) || x.tbUser.User_name.Contains(a)) && (x.StartDate >= sdate && x.EndDate <= edate)).OrderByDescending(x => x.ProjectId).ToList();
        }
        else
        {
            tbtask = entity.tbltasks.Include(x => x.tblproject).Include(x => x.tbUser).Where(x => selectproject.Contains(x.ProjectId) && x.tblproject.company_id == c).OrderByDescending(x => x.ProjectId).ToList();
        }
        return tbtask;
    }
```

Comment: I have Found The solution now !!!!

Comment: This is my Method   public List<tbltask> gettaskssdata(int? c, int? userid, string a, string StartDate, string EndDate, int? ProjectID, int? statusid)
{

Comment: List<tbltask> tbtask = new List<tbltask>();
           DateTime sdate = (StartDate != "") ? Convert.ToDateTime(StartDate).Date : new DateTime();
           DateTime edate = (EndDate != "") ? Convert.ToDateTime(EndDate).Date : new DateTime();
           tbtask = entity.tbltasks.Include(x => x.tblproject).Include(x => x.tbUser).
               Where(x=>x.tblproject.company_id==c 
                   &&(ProjectID == 0 || ProjectID==x.tblproject.ProjectId) 
                   && (statusid==0 || statusid==x.tblstatu.StatusId)

Comment: && (a == "" || (x.TaskName.Contains(a) || x.tbUser.User_name.Contains(a)))
                   && ((StartDate == "" && EndDate == "") || ((x.StartDate >= sdate && x.EndDate <= edate)))).ToList();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 public List<tbltask> gettaskssdata(int? c, int? userid, string a, string StartDate, string EndDate, int? ProjectID, int? statusid)
    {
        List<tbltask> tbtask = new List<tbltask>();
        DateTime sdate = (StartDate != "") ? Convert.ToDateTime(StartDate).Date : new DateTime();
        DateTime edate = (EndDate != "") ? Convert.ToDateTime(EndDate).Date : new DateTime();
        tbtask = entity.tbltasks.Include(x => x.tblproject).Include(x => x.tbUser).
            Where(x => x.tblproject.company_id == c
                && (ProjectID == 0 || ProjectID == x.tblproject.ProjectId)
                && (statusid == 0 || statusid == x.tblstatu.StatusId)
                && (a == "" || (x.TaskName.Contains(a) || x.tbUser.User_name.Contains(a)))
                && ((StartDate == "" && EndDate == "") || ((x.StartDate >= sdate && x.EndDate <= edate)))).ToList();



        return tbtask;


    }
```

Comment: Yes @ Fidel Your Answer Gives me an Idea About it

Answer (score 1):

Rather than having lots of `if` statements, you could have a single [LINQ](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_Integrated_Query) query.

The first thing to do is change your method to accept nullable values:

```
public List<tbltask> gettaskssdata(int? c, int? userid, string a, DateTime? StartDate, DateTime? EndDate, int? ProjectID, int? statusid)
{
```

Then modify your LINQ query. If the user provided a null value for a filter field, we want the row to get returned. Also, if the user actually provided a value, you do the comparison. For example:

```
tbtask = entity.tbltasks.Where(x => (!c.HasValue || x.tblproject.company_id == c.Value) && ...)
```

Comment: tbtask = entity.tbltasks.Include(x => x.tblproject).Include(x => x.tbUser).Where(x => (!c.HasValue || x.tblproject.company_id == c.Value) && ( !ProjectID.HasValue|| x.tblproject.ProjectId == ProjectID) && (!statusid.HasValue|| x.tblstatu.StatusId == statusid) && ( a==""|| x.TaskName.Contains(a) || x.tbUser.User_name.Contains(a)) && ( (!StartDate.HasValue && !EndDate.HasValue)|| x.StartDate >= StartDate && x.EndDate <= EndDate)).ToList();

Comment: The query is looking good. Perhaps split the StartDate & EndDate check in the following way...
                (!StartDate.HasValue) || x.StartDate >= StartDate) &&
                (!EndDate.HasValue) || x.EndDate <= EndDate))
                .ToList();